# MongoDB updates with java driver version 3.0

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm  migrating my aplications to MongoDb 3.0.2. I have no problems with inserts, finds and deletes. But,Problems with the update. Specially with the `eq()`.

In this sentence:

```
coll.updateOne(eq("_id", id), new Document("$set", new Document("name", name)));
```

The `id` variable is defined `ObjectId`. Eclipse gives me an error:

> *The method eq(String, ObjectId) is undefined for the 
>   type SystemDAO* (my java class).

What am I doing wrong? I followed the examples in the Mongo java driver documents.

Comment: please show the declaration and initialisation of `id` looks like it is not defined as `ObjectId`

Comment: public boolean modifyName(ObjectId id, String name) { coll.updateOne(eq("_id", id), new Document("$set", new Document("name", name)));}

Comment: I think that what Eclipse do not recognize is the eq function

Comment: Same error happens if I change for eq("name", "Jane") but now the error says ... method eq(String, String) ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to import the static method `eq` from the package `com.mongodb.client.model.Filters`.

add this infront of your class to your other imports:

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
```

In Eclipse it should give a quick-fix to import the right package if you do a mouse over on your error. But for static imports this does not work all the time.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It worked!!. I do not know why Eclipse didn´t give me the suggestion to add that import. It only gave me 1 quick fiz available: Create method eq(String, ObjectId) and nothing about add the import